# CCAI platform webhook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, contact-center

Is there a way to get req when message is send and received in ccai platform by agent and user?

I need to translate the user and agent languages so is there a way to get the details through webhook?